# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире после "главное"? Это не предикативное наречие на "о" и не в роли сказуемого, В правилах не нашла. В интернете часто пишут с тире, но мне кажется - это неверно.

Главное сократить время обработки деталей и нарастить выработку, не теряя в качестве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Главное сократить время обработки
> деталей и нарастить выработку, не
> теряя в качестве.*

***Главное*** -- подлежащее, ***сократить*** и ***нарастить*** -- сказуемые. Тире нужно.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106 :

> ***§ 12.** Тире ставится при
> выражении и подлежащего, и сказуемого
> (или только подлежащего, или только
> сказуемого) инфинитивом...*